# Call onCreate method of another class's method

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I want to call some method (another class)'s `onCreate()` method.

My code :

```
new BitmapHandler().loadBitmap(gridViewItem.getImage(), holder.imageItem);
```

The another class's methods :

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    final String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);

    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

Methods to occurs `NullPointerException`:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key); //this line occurs Exception
}
```

**The reason for `NullPointerException` is because I had to initialize onCreate().**

The another class's `onCreate()` method :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate"); //never called
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    RetainFragment retainFragment = RetainFragment.findOrCreateRetainFragment(getFragmentManager());
    mMemoryCache = retainFragment.mRetainedCache;
    if (mMemoryCache == null) {
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap> (cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
        retainFragment.mRetainedCache = mMemoryCache;
    }
}
```

How can I do for call the `onCreate()` in this situation? Or should the initialization elsewhere?

Thanks all, and TGIF :)

Comment: As i think you can't call onCreate. but what you can do is that just define some function and move that code into that function . call that function onCreate and also you can call that function using object of that class. i think this might help you.

Comment: in the other class let it extends from Activity and make the call of this method in onCreate()

Comment: And what happens if you move the code form `onCreate()` to `getBitmapFromMemCache()` method?

Comment: I have problem understanding this question. Basically onCreate is one of the methods called by lifecycle events, not you. If you want to transfer data (bitmap) between fragments or activities then this is incorrect way to do. I am just guessing because apparently you are trying to retrieve mMemoryCache from the second Activity.